# How to bring up the "Default Programs" dialog from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, controlpanel

How can I bring up the "Default Programs" dialog, using C#?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you're trying to do and what you have tried and found yourself.

Comment: I just want show default windows(xp,7) dialog of selection default apps for select extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[Code project solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13103/Calling-the-Open-With-dialog-box-from-your-applica)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the default Windows open file dialog, you can use the [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) class.

You will find an example at the link provided.